# [Bind(Include = does not work with collection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that looks like below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProduct([Bind(Include = "Id,MyCollection")] MyClass myClass)
```

and this is the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
    </div>
</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyCollection.First().A)</th>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyCollection.First().B)</th>
        <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyCollection.First().C)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in this.Model.Warnings)
{
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ValueFor(model => item.A)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.B)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.C)</td>
        </tr>
}
</table>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

when I click Save, it posts to the action but only Id is assigned to the object, not myCollection.

What do I need to do to include the collection when posting them to controller?

**Update**
Model is generated by Entity Framework

```
public abstract partial class MyBaseClass
{
    public Module()
    {
        this.MyCollection= new HashSet<Warning>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Warning> MyCollection { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    // more properties that aren't used on this controller
}
```

Comment: just show ur model class also..

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla The model is generated from entity framework, just updated on the question

Comment: why have u made public virtual ICollection<Warning> MyCollection { get; set; } property virtual?

Comment: Um, it's auto generated by EF. I have no idea. :(

Comment: here u r not taking model class to post data even u r using entity framework but model class is required to post data...

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work you need to understand how ASP.NET MVC handles model binding for a `List`.  Scott Hansleman has a [good post explaining this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Since your question was rather vague in terms of what the actual properties you're dealing with are, I put together a little example which successfully binds to a list:

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Initial test data
        var zoo = new Zoo()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Vilas Zoo",
            Animals = new List<Animal>()
            {
                new Animal() {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Red Panda"
                },
                new Animal() {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Sloth"
                },
                new Animal() {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Badger"
                },
            }
        };

        return View(zoo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(Zoo zoo)
    {
        return Json(zoo);
    }
}
```

### Model

```
public class Zoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
<h1>@Model.Id - @Model.Name</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (var i=0; i < Model.Animals.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Animals[i])
    }

    <button type="submit">Save it, yo</button>
}
```

Notice how I'm using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` and the actual index of the loop is being used in the call to `EditorFor`.

Comment: The data is shown correctly on the page but it doesn't get post back to the controller. Let me try to use for instead of foreach and I will let you know the result.

Comment: Displaying it is the easy part. The tricky part is making sure the names of the input fields are in the right format so when the HTTP request hits the ASP.NET MVC framework it can extract those values and give you the data to work with.

Comment: Is using `for` necessary?

Comment: Of course, I did. I just don't understand why I have to use `for`. The link on the answer just says that it's by design but that doesn't make sense for me since foreach can loop through the collection as well.

Comment: @Anonymous The reason you need to use the `for` is simply because you need to build out the HTML in a particular way for the ASP.NET MVC model binding to work.  I'm not sure how experienced you are with web development, but when you `POST` the data to the server you aren't sending C# objects, you're just sending plain ol' text.  The ASP.NET MVC framework has conventions for how it takes that text and transforms it into an object for your use in the method.  The link in my answer explains those rules *specifically* for binding to a collection.  Does that help clarify?  If not let me know.